# Storing a string array in a class member function and returning it

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class

Hello I would appreciate if someone took the time to write a simple way to store a string array in a class member function and return that value in a main function.

Here is what i have. Id like to store 4 different authors in this array and print it later.

```
  void setauthor(string a[4])
    {
        string authors[4] = a[4];
    }
```

thanks

Comment: `std::array<std::string, 4>`

Comment: Use std::vector.  It is a lot easier to pass, copy and store.

Comment: Im sorry to say that i have started a class in C++ and just learning the basics and i have not learned anything like a vector.

Comment: In terms of education for beginners, `std::vector` and `std::array` are more basic than raw array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a simple for loop ??
Though you need an extra parameter, but if the author number is fixed then this should be the easiest.

```
void setauthor(string a[4],int number)
{
    string author[4];
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        author[i]= a[i];
        cout<<author[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass `number`? Why are you printing `author[i]` at every step? Why are you not using `std::copy`?

Comment: author[i] was used for check , and i didn't used std::copy because i wanted to keep it as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy an array on construction like that, but you can do it afterward:

```
void setauthor(string a[4])
{
    string authors[4];
    std::copy(a, a+4, authors);
}
```

You'll need to `#include <algorithm>` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `std::array<std::string, 4>` which has copy semantic:

```
void setauthor(std::array<std::string, 4> a)
{
    std::array<std::string, 4> authors = a;
}
```

You'll need to `#include <array>` at the top.

You can even declare an alias to make it easier to write:

```
using four_strings = std::array<std::string, 4>;

void setauthor(four_strings a)
{
    four_strings authors = a;
}
```

Comment: So how would i store the strings into that code. Liike this?   **Book[i].setauthor(author)**